# Assigning a Letter in C

Tags: c, string, printf

I'm trying to assign a letter grade based on a students total score. Then try to print that letter grade, but I am printing a null. Here is the code that I am using:

```
int FinalScore;
    FinalScore = q1w+q2w+q3w+q4w+midiw+midiiw+finalw;

// Determine the letter Grade
if (FinalScore>=0 && FinalScore <= 59)
{   
    char LetterGrade[20];
    strcpy(LetterGrade,"F");
}
if(FinalScore>=60 && FinalScore <=69)
{
    char LetterGrade[20];
    strcpy(LetterGrade,"D");
}
if(FinalScore>=70 && FinalScore <=79)
{
    char LetterGrade[20];
    strcpy(LetterGrade,"C");
}
if(FinalScore>=80 && FinalScore <=89)
{
    char LetterGrade[20];
    strcpy(LetterGrade,"B");
}
if(FinalScore>=90 )
{
    char LetterGrade[20];
    strcpy(LetterGrade,"A");
}
printf("%s",&LetterGrade);
```

Any ideas why I am getting the null?? Thanks.

Comment: where did you define `LetterGrade`?

Comment: isnt it being defined by "char LetterGrade[20]"?

Comment: You can just use `char LetterGrade` and then `LetterGrade = 'A'`...

Comment: `char LetterGrade[20];` has gone out of scope by the time you try to `printf("%s",&LetterGrade);`

Comment: this is wrong on 3 levels :  
1) LetterGrade is not know in the scope outside the If statements. 
2) Even in these scopes it is never initialized.
3) Why are you using a char array for a single letter ..?!

Comment: Exactly! The variable `LetterGrade` is defined inside the `if`'s scope. After that, it goes out of scope and nothing can work with it.

Comment: The trouble is that when the code leaves `if(FinalScore>=80 && FinalScore <=89)
{
    char LetterGrade[20];
    strcpy(LetterGrade,"B");
}`, the variable `LetterGrade` ceases to exist and cannot be printed.  Indeed, your code should not be compiling unless you also have another variable `LetterGrade` defined at function, or file, scope.  But if you have another such variable, delete the declarations in the `if` statements.  Also, if you use GCC to compile, consider compiling with `-Wshadow` to give you warnings when your local declarations shadow more global ones.

Comment: The code as shown won't compile, as for the `printf()` `LetterGrade` isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any utility of creating a string (`char[20]`), instead of a simple `char`, since it's going to end up having only one character in the end. II wrote the [code](http://cpp.sh/8cx7) that seems to work just fine.

The problem with your code is that `LetterGrade` is declared in `if`'s scope, so, by the time you try to print it, it's already gone out of scope, as I also mentioned in my comment.

**Very important!** As @Jite, mentioned in his comment, notice the `%c` format specifier instead of the `%s`, in the `printf`.

I hope that fits your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int FinalScore = 60;
    char LetterGrade;

    // Determine the letter Grade
    if(FinalScore>=0  && FinalScore <= 59) LetterGrade = 'F';
    else if(FinalScore>=60 && FinalScore <=69) LetterGrade = 'D';
    else if(FinalScore>=70 && FinalScore <=79) LetterGrade = 'C';
    else if(FinalScore>=80 && FinalScore <=89) LetterGrade = 'B';
    else LetterGrade = 'A';

    printf("%c", LetterGrade);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note the use of `%c` instead of `%s` as format specifier for `printf`! Very important because if `LetterGrade` is of type `char` and used like above, then there's no NUL termination...

Comment: Something like that, @alk?

Answer (score 3):

LetterGrade is defined in a different scope than you are trying to utilize it.

remove every instance of `char LetterGrade[20];` and move it to just above your if statements.

```
Finalscore = . . .
char LetterGrade[20];
if (. . .
```

Additionally I'd recommend just using a `char`, not sure why you're using a `char[]` in the first place to store one character.

Answer (score 3):

In all of your definitions of LetterGrade, you have declared the variable within an if block. Therefore, it does not exist outside of any of those blocks, and when you print, you are trying to print something that does not exist. (i.e. out of scope)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `Lettergrade` in your `if`, it is local to that `if` and is not defined outside.

And since you want to print only one letter, you don't need an array of `char`. A simple `char` variable is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems there.
You are defining LetterGrade within the scope of if statements which will mean that they will be out of scope in modern C compilers IIRC by the time you make it to the printf statement.
Also your print statement is going to try to interpret &LetterGrade as a pointer to character while in fact it is a pointer to a char array, which is more like a pointer to a pointer to char.  Try just printf("%s", LetterGrade).

Answer (score 2):

You need not to  specify & while displaying string.

You have declared LetterGrade in different scopes. The global scope LetterGrade value does not change when u declare and modify the same thing inside a block. It gets block scope.
So remove all declarations of LetterGrade inside blocks. The global one is enough.
[scope-rules-in-c](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/)

To just display grade why can't you use char instead of char array or string.

Comment: It's just the same, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int FinalScore;
char LetterGrade;

FinalScore = q1w+q2w+q3w+q4w+midiw+midiiw+finalw;


if (FinalScore>=0 && FinalScore <= 59)
{   
    LetterGrade = 'F';    
}
if(FinalScore>=60 && FinalScore <=69)
{
    LetterGrade = 'D';  
}
if(FinalScore>=70 && FinalScore <=79)
{
    LetterGrade = 'C';
}
if(FinalScore>=80 && FinalScore <=89)
{
    LetterGrade = 'B';
}
if(FinalScore>=90 )
{
    LetterGrade = 'A';
}
printf("%c", LetterGrade);
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of comparisons can be reduced by dividing the final score by 10 before comparing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int FinalScore = ...;
  char LetterGrade;

  FinalScore /= 10;

  // Determine the letter Grade
  if (FinalScore < 5) LetterGrade = 'F';
  else if (FinalScore < 7) LetterGrade = 'D';
  else if (FinalScore < 8) LetterGrade = 'C';
  else if (FinalScore < 9) LetterGrade = 'B';
  else LetterGrade = 'A';

  printf("%c\n", LetterGrade);

  return 0;
}
```

Even more effcient in terms of performance would be a map:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char ScoreToGradeMap[10] = {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'};

int main(void)
{
  int FinalScore = ...;
  char LetterGrade;

  FinalScore /= 10;

  if (0 > FinalScore) FinalScore = 0;
  else if (9 < FinalScore) FinalScore = 9;

  LetterGrade = ScoreToGradeMap[FinalScore];

  printf("%c\n", LetterGrade);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the first version you give, the change of number of comparisons is not due to dividing by 10.   It is because you changed the nature of the tests.  Your approaches will also not work if the boundary between two grades is not a multiple of 10.  (e.g. if the boundary between grades C and D is 65 rather than 70) - which does happen fairly often in practice.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code is showing two major problems.

```
1) the character array 'LetterGrade' is only visible within the code block where it is defined.
   Suggest defining once, before all the testing of the students score
2a) LetterGrade is not visible at the printf() statement, so the code will not compile
2b) when calling printf() do not pass the address of LetterGrade
    suggest: printf("%s", LetterGrade);
```